# how to use SIFTGPU and ORB in RGBDSLAM

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbd6dslam, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried using SIFTGPU with rgbdslam to built a map. I launched rgbdslam.launch file for using SIFTGPU.

While, I tried mapping with this file. I got error -> Can't create OpenGL context! SiftGPU cannot be used.Detection of keypoints failed

NOTE: Also, in the launch file i don't understand the comment => If SIFTGPU is enabled in CMakeLists.txt, use SURF here

And I would like to use ORB in rgbdslam.

Any suggestions about this error and ideas to use ORB?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40415/how-to-use-siftgpu-and-orb-in-rgbdslam/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need an X server with opengl enabled for SiftGPU to work. So you might not be able to use it when ssh'ing into another machine.
To use ORB, just put ORB into the detector and extractor type parameters and BRUTEFORCE into the matcher parameter of your launch-file (see rgbdslam_sample_config.launch for a list of all available options, their names and their default values).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-08-06**:
Now, I can use ORB. But I can't install X server for opengl.. Does using siftGPU or installing Xserver have any hardware requirements?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-08-06**:
I guess not, if you have the mesa opengl implementation and there should be a xserver that runs without graphics cards. But if you don't have a hardware gpu you probably should rather use SIFT instead of SIFTGPU. How does ORB work out for you?

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-08-07**:
While, using SIFTGPU it gives one more error. 'detection of keypoints failed'. I used SIFT from bdslam_sample_config.launch.The map start to built but I got an error 'Non-Positive Mahalanobis Distance for vectors 4.2039e-45'. Is this a problem?
Yes, ORB worked even in tougher environment.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-09-06**:
The message 'detection of keypoints failed' is a consequence of the missing OpenGL context. I don't know what's the problem with the Mahalanobis distance, sorry. It should be safe to ignore. e-45 is pretty close to zero...

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-09-06**:
Hm, I don't know what's the problem there, sorry.